# Incorrect syntax near ')'. while creating table

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am newbie to sqlserver and i have came across an error which is :

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near ')'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolea
n breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception
, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObj
ect stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand
 cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler,
TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName,
Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSou
rce`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean
asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at KellenTechnology.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\Mohit\Documents\V
isual Studio 2013\Projects\KellenTechnology\KellenTechnology\Program.cs:line 37
ClientConnectionId:d9ec7a79-87d2-40f9-83f9-dc7b08c05153
```

And the code for this error cause is the connection string below:

```
 string sqlStatement2 = "CREATE TABLE " + Table2Name + "" +
      "(line_id AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ," + 
        "line_full_name CHAR(50) NOT NULL,"+
        " network_id INTEGER FOREIGN KEY)";
```

Could some one please let me know the cause of this problem ? How to fix it ?

Comment: Foreign key has to point somewhere...

Comment: That query is quite vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9378/SQL-Injection-Attacks-and-Some-Tips-on-How-to-Prev)... ;(

Comment: @kape123: Just because a SQL string is concatenated doesn't automatically mean that it is vulnerable to SQL injection.  It depends on where the `Table2Name` variable comes from.  And since this is the table name in a `CREATE TABLE` statement, it's not like OP can do parameter binding in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`autoincrement` is not a SQL Server keyword.  I think you intend:

```
 string sqlStatement2 = "CREATE TABLE " + Table2Name + "" + 
                         "(line_id int not null identity(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY, " +
                          "line_full_name CHAR(50) NOT NULL," +
                          " network_id INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES network(network_id))";
```

In addition, `FOREIGN KEY` requires a table reference.

Comment: also what it means by doing  "identity(1, 1)"  ?

Comment: It means start autogenerating primary key from 1 with increment 1

Comment: @myroman why can't i do  AUTOINCREMENT instead ? what's wrong when i do this? (It gives error in that line when i tried :  Incorrect syntax near ',')

Comment: @ajpr . . . One is MySQL syntax.  The other is SQL Server syntax.  Databases do things differently.